# Getting elements by a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to this all so please forgive me if this is a really daft question. I'm trying to make a simple system for users to rank different options, but I can't make it work. Basically I'm trying to make it so the upvote/downvote functions work for as many policies as needed, without having to code a new one for each.

Is anyone able to point out what I'm doing wrong here?

https://codepen.io/gordonmaloney/pen/GRWpgyj

```
var votes = 0;

function upvote(policy){
  var policy = policy;
  votes ++;
  document.getElementById('#' + policy).innerHTML = votes + " votes";
}

function downvote(policy){
  var policy = policy;
  votes --;
  document.getElementById('#' + policy).innerHTML = votes + " votes";
}
```

```
<p id="vote1">0 votes</p>
<button onclick="upvote(vote1)">&#x1F60D;</button>
<button onclick="downvote(vote1)">&#x1F44E;</button>
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Strings require delimiters. `(vote1)` should be `('vote1')` or even better, avoid inline handlers entirely, they have no place in modern JavaScript

Comment: just put your references in quotes `onclick="upvote('vote1')"` - otherwise your code is trying to find a variable called 'vote1' and will error out.

Comment: `var policy = policy;` Huh? Why declare a new variable with the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple changes I made.

First is what the comments said, `onclick="upvote('vote1')"`

Second is the `getElementById` call: you don't need to prefix it with #: `document.getElementById(policy)`

The last thing I won't fix for you is that `votes` is a global variable that each of these functions accesses, no matter which policy it is, so when you update the votes for one policy, you're updating ALL of the votes.

What you might want instead is an object that manages each policies votes, with some functions for initiating the value if it's the first time someone's voted and updating the value if it's not the first time. An Object who, at it's simplest form, would just look like this:

```
{ 'vote1' : 2, 'vote2': 3 }
```

https://codepen.io/SuperList/pen/xxqwGVw?editors=1111

Comment: Thank you!! So that really was as silly a mistake as I thought. Will work out the votes variable so they're unique - thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you put the example in codepen instead of a Stack Snippet?

Comment: @Barmar because that's where OP put it, and it was easy to click 'fork'

Answer (score 0):

You should make your upvote and downvote parameters strings and your upvote/downvotes should look like the following:

```js
function upvote(policy){
  votes ++;
  document.getElementById(policy).innerHTML = votes + " votes";
}

function downvote(policy){
  votes --;
  document.getElementById(policy).innerHTML = votes + " votes";
}
```

Also, you do not need to reassign the `policy` value to itself.

```js
var votes = 0;

function upvote(policy){
  votes ++;
  document.getElementById(policy).innerHTML = votes + " votes";
}

function downvote(policy){
  votes --;
  document.getElementById(policy).innerHTML = votes + " votes";
}
```

```css
h1 {
 text-align: center; 
}  
button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.policy-description {
  font-style: italic;
}

.policies {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.policy-box {
flex-shrink: 3;
width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Pick your favourite policy</h1>
<div class="policies">
  
  
<div class="policy-box">
<p>Policy 1</p>
<p class="policy-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ligula est, pretium vel orci at, pulvinar tempus risus</p>
<p id="vote1">0 votes</p>
<button onclick="upvote('vote1')">&#x1F60D;</button>
<button onclick="downvote('vote1')">&#x1F44E;</button>
</div>

  
<div class="policy-box">
<p>Policy 2</p>
<p class="policy-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ligula est, pretium vel orci at, pulvinar tempus risus</p>
<p id="vote2">0 votes</p>
<button onclick="upvote('vote2')">&#x1F60D;</button>
<button onclick="downvote('vote2')">&#x1F44E;</button>
</div>
  
</div>
```